# Overriding == operator in flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await, overriding

I have this drift table:

```
@DataClassName('User')
class Users extends Table {
  TextColumn get id => text().clientDefault(() => uuid.v4())();
  TextColumn get username => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get password => text().nullable()();
    
  @override
  Set<Column> get primaryKey => {id};

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Users && _____;

  @override
  int get hashCode => username.hashCode ^ password.hashCode;

}
```

And I wanted to override the == operator. to do that I need to first decrypt my username and password. but my decryption method is async:

```
  static Future<String?> decrypt(String? cipherText) async {
    if (cipherText == null) return null;

    final key = await getEncryptionKey();
    final decoded = base64.decode(cipherText);
    final iv = IV.fromLength(ivLength);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));

    final encrypted = Encrypted(decoded.sublist(16));
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);
    return decrypted;
  }
```

I couldn't find a way to run it synchorniously.
Is there a way to do this? maybe another approach?

thanks!

Comment: You should not need to "decrypt" anything in an ==. I'm confused by your goal.  To say they are ==, you should simply compare the encrypted values.  If those are different, then they must be !=

Comment: different encrypted values can be decrypted to the same string using AES and random IV.

Comment: But you'll still need to treat those as different objects since they are holding different representations, much like 1 != 1.0 even though mathematically they're the same.

Comment: but I dont want to treat them differently, I want to check if they actually have the same data, not encrypted data

Comment: You should create a separate ".isSame" and use that where you need it.  But at a low level, == and hashCode should be fast and synchronous.  Two different objects that encode the same value two different ways are *different*.